# Issue with deserialisation of map of an abstract JAVA class

Tags: java, jackson, hashmap, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to send a HTTP request to an API which accepts a JSON request body in this format

```
{
  "firstName" : "XYZ",
  "family" : {
     "commonDetails" : {
         "secondName" : "ABC"
     }, 
     "1" : "Mother name",
     "2" : "Father name",
     "3" : "Spouse name"
  }
}
```

So I have defined a request payload the below way.

```
public class UserDetails {
   private String firstName;
   private Map<String, AbstractFamilyDetails> details;
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties("type")
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FamilyCommonDetails.class, name = "COMMON_DETAILS"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FamilyIndividual.class, name = "FAMILY")
})
public abstract class AbstractFamilyDetails {
    private String type;
}
```

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class FamilyCommonDetails extends AbstractFamilyDetails {
    private String secondName;

    @Builder
    public FamilyCommonDetails(String secondName) {
        super("COMMON_DETAILS");
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    public FamilyCommonDetails() {
        super("COMMON_DETAILS");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.secondName;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class FamilyIndividual extends AbstractFamilyDetails {
    private String individual;

    @Builder
    public FamilyIndividual(String individual) {
        super("FAMILY");
        this.individual = individual;
    }

    public FamilyIndividual() {
        super("FAMILY");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.individual;
    }
}
```

But when I debug what json payload I'm hitting the server with turns out to be

```
{
  "firstName" : "XYZ",
  "family" : {
     "commonDetails" : {
         "secondName" : "ABC",
     }, 
     "1" : {"individual": "Mother name"},
     "2" : {"individual": "Father name"},
     "3" : {"individual": "Spouse name"}
  }
}
```

Where is it that I'm going wrong? Do I have to define a custom jackson deserialiser to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation on the `individual` field.

See: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html

Answer (score 0):

Have tried using `@JsonUnwrapped` as @user3296624 suggested. However it didn't work. There is an open issue on jackson-databind related to the same. [Issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/171)

Have tried `@JsonAnySetter` too, which did't help.

So, modified my request model to `private Map<String, Object> details` and discarded `AbstractFamilyDetails` as the last resort and used it accordingly. Not an ideal solution. But worked.